# NHibernate component loading as null when many-to-one NULL, despite several non-null properties

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I understand that when all the properties of a mapped component are null in the database, NHibernate will set the component to null.  However, in the following case the component is being set to null if the many-to-one item *LevelOfInvolvement* is null, despite the fact that all the other properties of the component are **not** null.

Changing the value of the *LevelOfInvolvement* column in the database will cause the component to be null or not, regardless of the value of the other fields.

Here is the maping in full:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class name="NHS.WebTeam.LPTInvolvementHub.Activity, NHS.WebTeam.LPTInvolvementHub" table="[Activity]" lazy="false" optimistic-lock="version" where="Deleted=0" >
    <id name="ID" type="Int32" column="ID" unsaved-value="0">
      <generator class="hilo">
        <param name="table">NHibernateHiLo</param>
        <param name="column">NextValue</param>
        <param name="max_lo">100</param>
      </generator>
    </id>

    <version name="Version"/>
    <property name="Deleted" />
    <property name="LastUpdateBy" />
    <property name="LastUpdateDate" />

    <many-to-one name="Service" column="ServiceID"></many-to-one>
    <property name="Title"></property>
    <property name="Abstract"></property>
    <property name="ProposedDate"></property>
    <property name="DueDate"></property>
    <property name="ActualDate"></property>
    <property name="Rationale"></property>
    <many-to-one name="PreAssessment" column="PreAssessmentID"></many-to-one>
    <many-to-one name="PostAssessment" column="PostAssessmentID"></many-to-one>

    <component name="InvolvementChecklist">
      <property name="Impact" column="InvolvementChecklist_Impact"></property>
      <property name="RewardsAndRecognition" column="InvolvementChecklist_RewardsAndRecognition"></property>
      <property name="Training" column="InvolvementChecklist_Training"></property>
      <property name="LogisticalIssues" column="InvolvementChecklist_LogisticalIssues"></property>
      <property name="Feedback" column="InvolvementChecklist_Feedback"></property>
      <property name="DueRegard" column="InvolvementChecklist_DueRegard"></property>
      <property name="SupportRequiredFromTheTeam" column="InvolvementChecklist_SupportRequiredFromTheTeam"></property>
      <property name="QualityAssurance" column="InvolvementChecklist_QualityAssurance"></property>
      <property name="NonComplianceReason" column="InvolvementChecklist_NonComplianceReason"></property>
      <many-to-one name="LevelOfInvolvement" column="InvolvementChecklist_LevelOfInvolvementID"></many-to-one>
    </component>

  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

The code to load the entity is simply:

```
entity = NHibernateSession.Load(persitentType, id);
```

I am using NHibernate version 3.3.1

This seems a relatively simple mapping, but I cannot find any reference to others having similar problems.

Comment: do you have nhibernate profiler to see the translated SQL to test what it returns?

Comment: I don't have NHibernate Profiler, but can get the SQL via Log4Net.  Running the query returns the expected values for the component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to returning null if all of the component members are null, I believe NHibernate will also treat a component as null if **any** non-nullable members are null. By default a `<many-to-one>` mapping creates a non-nullable member, which I think would cause the behaviour you're seeing. Try changing the `LevelOfInvolement` mapping to allow nulls:

```
<many-to-one 
    name="LevelOfInvolvement" 
    column="InvolvementChecklist_LevelOfInvolvementID" 
    not-null="false" />
```